# Can we generate report of a salesforce record in form of google slide?

Tags: salesforce, google-slides-api, google-slides

I am quite new to salesforce. Recently, I was assigned to work on salesforce integration with google slide. Basically, the requirement is to being able to generate salesforce record report in google slide. I am looking forward to hearing from our communities here. Thank you in advance.

I am glad to get some clue out from anyone who ever had experiences using salesforce with google products like google docs or sheet or google slide etc... I am so grateful for your help.